# Unable to access MetaModel entity attributes

Tags: jpa, metamodel

I have tried to access the MetaModel entity attributes/variables using the code below:

```
CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
         Metamodel m = entityManager.getMetamodel();
         EntityType<User> User_ = m.entity(User.class);
        Root<User> userRoot = criteria.from(User.class);
        criteria.where(builder.equal(userRoot.get(User_.email)), user.getEmail());
```

but email cannot be resolved or is not a field.
Is it mandatory to create StaticMetaModel class for User class. i.e., "User_" ???

If YES, please see the link http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjbq.html
here, you can find the below code:

```
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Pet> Pet_ = m.entity(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.where(cb.equal(pet.get(Pet_.name), "Fido"));
```

Please help me here.

Comment: So your question is "is it necessary to create the User_ class to use "User_.email"" ????!!! Well obviously. If the class doesn't exist then how can Java load the class?

Comment: Then how below code (which is in Oracle documentation) works ?CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Pet> Pet_ = m.entity(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.where(cb.equal(pet.get(Pet_.name), "Fido")); Also if staticMetamodel class is required then what is the need of below 2 lines: Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Pet> Pet_ = m.entity(Pet.class); Please explain

Comment: Pet_ is part of the GENERATED STATIC METAMODEL. Read documentation http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql_criteria.html#metamodel

Comment: I agree User_ is part of StaticMetamodel. My concern is, by creating User_ with StaticMetamodel annotation we can write as below: CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> userRoot = criteria.from(User.class);
criteria.select(userRoot);
criteria.where(builder.equal(userRoot.get(User_.email), user.getEmail()));
But in the documentation  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjbq.html , Pet_ is obtained using 2 lines of code 1. MetaModel-> 2. EntityType             What is the need of getting Metamodel class from EntityType as above ?

Comment: Who said this "Oracle tutorial" you refer to is correct? It isn't. Look at the DOCUMENTATION of the implementation you are using. Look at the JPA spec. They are the definitive references

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That Oracle documentation you refer to is utterly wrong. The STATIC metamodel is generated by an annotation processor. It is not obtained via the JPA Metamodel class.

The STATIC (canonical) metamodel class with "_" is not an `EntityType` object.
See the JPA spec section 6.2.1.1 and documentation such as [this one](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql_criteria.html#metamodel).

Comment: Its my bad to follow oracle doc. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Well, its Oracle's bad for publishing such incorrect info (they are *supposed* to be the people who promote this technology). I've raised an issue against them https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-121